# Gravity on Instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles

I am trying to add gravity to instances and it went pretty well until I realized it looked like it was glued to it's base surface, so I made a normal particle system to compare and it definetely feels glued to the surface, is it any possible to get the same result in geometry nodes ?

**3D View**

[image: 3D View]

**Nodes**

[image: Nodes]

And here's the file:

[image]

Comment: The node screen capture is very small, can you upload a better image or share your file?

Comment: @lemon sorry about that, I edited the file into the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your setup is, you have animated location, rotation and scale of the base object that holds the *Geometry Nodes* modifier. You can think of it as being the parent object to everything generated by the GN nodetree.

Other than the regular particle system in Blender, the points are like the mesh of the GN object. They change their position within the object (like for example vertices moved with a shape key), but they are bound to the translations of the object they belong to.

Now you can do one of two things:

1. Delete the keyframes for the GN object. Use a separate external object and animate its movement. Bring it into the GN nodetree with an *Object Info* node (set to *Relative*) and distribute the points on it.

   [image: separate object]

The second method would be:

2. Delete the keyframes for the GN object. Add a *Transform Geometry* node between the *Grid* node and the *Distribute Points on Faces* node. Animate the transform values. But beware, you have scaled the GN object to 0.225 without applying the scale. This means when you set the *Transform Geometry* node to move the grid 1 m on X, it will only be moved 0.225 m.

   [image: transform geometry]

Comment: The first solution did it for me, tysm for the help !

Answer (score 3):

They appear to be glued because you are generating new ones at each step of the simulation:

[image]

Instead you should do something like this:

[image]

---

This is not related to the question, but quite similar setting at the output:

[image]

As the instances are deleted after the simulation zone, they're still part of the simulation. This is not visible as they are deleted, though, they still weight the simulation part.

You should instead do something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not the point of the question, see my answer. The point is the emitted particles move with the emitter instead of keep falling where they were emitted.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, ok, maybe...